# Dropbox app like video & audio preview

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, dropbox, avplayer

How do I generate a audio and video preview function exactly like it is in Dropbox iPhone app? Is it AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayer? Or is it custom made controls and slider? I need exact same controls and slider option. 
Also I need to play the video and audio using a web service. The files are on the server. So I need to buffer them and play them as they get buffered.
Please suggest some help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is in the Dropbox app.

`AVPlayer` doesn't include any search etc. controls, and adding them yourself is fiddly. Consider instead `MPMoviePlayerViewController` (a newer controller class which wraps the old `MPMoviePlayerController`).

Be aware of the iOS limitations of whatever classes/techniques you use. For example, if you want your code to work pre-iOS3.2, you need to use `MPMoviePlayerController` directly (when running on iOS < 3.2) instead of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. If the device iOS >= 3.2, you use `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

Disclaimer: I don't know all of your requirements etc. For a good overview of the complicated history of multimedia APIs, check out [this page](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/03/history-of-ios-media-apis-iphone-os-20.html).